# Date_start and date _stop default api fb

Tags: api, date

I have the following url where I am using campaigns, I want to request the information per day but even if I put "date preset" or "time range" I always get date_start and stop as seen in the image, my question is:  it possible to remove date_star and date_stop or why does it default? and if it can be removed, how can you request the information per day?

My url :
https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/act_id/campaigns?&fields=id,status,objective,insights{account_name,campaign_name,adset_name,impressions,reach,clicks,frequency,unique_clicks,cost_per_inline_post_engagement}&limit=100&date_preset{today}&access_token=" "

What i get is:
[date obtained when making the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59J6T.png)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `&date_preset={today}` instead of `&date_preset{today}`

Comment: If I put it like this it gives me the following error:  "message": "(#100) For field 'campaigns': date_preset must be one of the following values: today, yesterday..."

Comment: So put correct value `today` instead of `{today}`

Comment: thanks, I already changed to date_preset = today but it keeps giving me the monthly date with date_start and date_stop